# Storable.pm - corrupt when saving to non-truncated file

Tags: perl, hash, storable

In my production environment we have had what we believe to be a
corrupt storable hash, created by Storable.pm. I am unable to replicate the behaviour in Dev, which has made it hard to diagnose exactly.

The code has been working for a long time, and the change that made it
break was deleting from the hash. Up until recently, the hash either
stayed the same size, or grew.

The file is opened in readwrite, and then store_fd writes to the file.
As the hash is now (sometimes) smaller, it will write say 1000bytes to
this 2000byte file. The tail 1000 bytes are old, garbage data. In my
test cases, when I retrieve the hash, the garbage data is ignored, as
expected.

```
open( $sf, "+< $self->{mod_state_filename}" );
flock( $sf, LOCK_EX );
$self->{mod_state} = fd_retrieve($sf);
delete ($self->{mod_state}{"somekey"});
seek( $sf, 0, 0 );
store_fd( $self->{mod_state}, $sf );
flock( $sf, LOCK_UN )
close($sf);
```

My questions:

1. Should this work, or is it
   imperative that I truncate the file?
2. Does the stored hash use some kind
   of file terminator character? If so,
   what is it?
3. The above code, deleting
   and adding and deleting and adding,
   works perfectly in my test case. Can
   you suggest any test case sequence
   that might cause it to fail, due to
   the non-truncated file? (I know this
   is a really vague question, so feel
   free to ignore it).

Comment: Why aren't you using storable's built in store and retrieve functions.  Storable also supports locking http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.24/Storable.pm#ADVISORY_LOCKING

Comment: I know it does, but I didn't write the code. It was this way (except for the delete) years before I inherited it.

I'd consider change the code to use Storable::locking, but I have no idea if it will (and suspect it probably won't) fix my problem. (I could try, but the problem only appears in production, so I need to be sure of the fix. I can't trial-and-error).

I don't think my problem is due to locking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well `Storable` deals with trailing garbage, but surely it can't hurt to add

```
truncate $sf, tell($sf);
```

after the call to `store_fd`, eliminating all doubt about whether it can deal with it now and in the future.

Comment: Peter, don't call me Shirley.   I agree, but I wanted to confirm it in test conditions first, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I thought I updated this.

I asked perl5-porters, and got answers to the question.

I've not implemented the fix, as I can't replicate under test, so don't want to push to my production env, my work-around is safer for the moment.

Truncating is definitely a good idea, based on the answers from perl5-porters.

I didn't know someone had (or could!) put a bounty on my question.